# Run set names query, and json unicode on laravel

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, unicode

I'm new on Laravel
and I search for a way to run queries
I'm not talking about select etc...
I want to run this query:

```
 SET NAMES 'utf8'
```

This is question number one,
Now question number two:
I have data writen in hebrew in my db
and when I do on Laravel this code:

```
    $todolist = DB::select('select * from todo');
    return $todolist;
```

I get this result:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"\u05d1\u05dc\u05d4 \u05d1\u05dc\u05d4 \u05d1\u05dc\u05d4","done":0},{"id":2,"name":"\u05d1\u05dc\u05d4 \u05d1\u05dc\u05d4 \u05d1\u05dc\u05d4","done":1}]
```

What is this? unicode? how can I turn it to hebrew again?
My mission is to send it back to client side and then show it on the web page
How can I translate this from unicode to hebrew with Java Script ?

Comment: @Musa but what about the unicode chars?

Comment: I would store everything in UTF8 in the database. Problem solved? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `statement` method of the DB class, like so:

```
DB::statement("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

I'm not entirely aware of the situation but I would recommend this be within a migration.

Regarding the unicode characters, those should render in views correctly and should be usable within Javascript (see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LZpOqY)

Comment: Hey @Illizian thanks , I dont need it for the views I need it for ajax , and when I get into the page from the broswer I see the unicod the characters,(thanks for the first one)

Comment: @Harmanmet see my edit, I've added a Codepen with a demo of the browser displaying the Hebrew for the inserted Unicode characters.

Comment: @Harmanmet Please accept my answer (the tick besides my answer)